# In Java, why are the private data members accessible outside the class if written like this?

Tags: java, class, private, access-modifiers

Usually, if `type` is a *private* member of a class named `Pass`, and `obj` is a reference to object of `Pass` class, we cannot do `obj.type` because `type` is *private* member so that would give error.

In `copy()` method, `a` is passed as a parameter where `a` is a reference to `Pass` object.

By the same logic, we should also not be allowed to do `a.type`.

But this code runs fine. Why? This is my doubt.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pass ob1 = new Pass(10,'c');
    Pass ob2 = new Pass(20,'f');

    ob1.print();
    ob2.print();

    ob1.copy(ob2);

    ob1.print();
    ob2.print();
    }
}

class Pass {
    private int number = 0;
    private char type = 'a';

    public Pass(int i, char t) {
        this.number = i;
        this.type = t;
    }

    public void copy(Pass a) {
        this.number = a.number;
        this.type = a.type;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(number + " =>" + type);
    }
}
```

Comment: private means that something can only becaccessed by things in the same class. Not only from the same object.

Comment: Visibility modifiers describe *class* visibility, not *object* visibility.

Comment: They're not being accessed outside their class.  You're  confusing 'class' and 'object' (or 'instance').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the method is in the same class, it can access private members of other instances. `private` only means that only functions *in the class* can access it, with no restrictions on which object is doing the accessing.

Answer (score 4):

There are four types of Java access modifiers:

1. **Private**: The access level of a private modifier is only within the class. It cannot be accessed from outside the class.
2. **Default**: The access level of a default modifier is only within the package. It cannot be accessed from outside the package. If you do not specify any access level, it will be the default.
3. **Protected**: The access level of a protected modifier is within the package and outside the package through child class. If you do not make the child class, it cannot be accessed from outside the package.
4. **Public**: The access level of a public modifier is everywhere. It can be accessed from within the class, outside the class, within the package, and outside the package.

In your case, you access the `type` variable inside the `Pass` class. So even though it is a private variable, you have permission to access it.